# DataTables TableTools buttons not working correctly (simple example)

Tags: jquery, export, datatables, export-to-excel, tabletools

I am trying to use the newest tableTool 2.2.0 and i have made a little and simple example [jsfiddle.net/9ZTGb/](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZTGb/)

COPY and PRINT buttons seems to respond, but the "Copy" is resulting "blank", and "CSV","Excel","PDF" seems not workinkg at all..

this is the table:

```
<table id="tblExport" class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>@lsmith</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Williams</td>
            <td>@mwills</td>
            <td>Pending</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Jeremy</td>
            <td>Jones</td>
            <td>@jj</td>
            <td>Success</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Carlos</td>
            <td>Martin</td>
            <td>@cmar</td>
            <td>Suspende</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and this is the js script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#tblExport').dataTable({
         "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
             "oTableTools": {
             "sSwfPath": "https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                 "aButtons": ["copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf", "print"]
         }
     });
 });
```

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me why it isn't working. the example here and the jsfiddle i tried to make as simple as possible, but still not really working..

Comment: Hey do you get any solution for this ? ... as i am also facing same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837595/datatables-tabletools-not-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sSwfPath : Flash file Security is the Issue:

Solution:

Step 1: Check For sDom Property.

Step 2: Check the SWF Path is correct. If its correct

Step 3: Open Flash Manager :

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Under 3rd Tab, Global Settings 
Add the Site Url Which contains SWF Path.
Select Always Allow Option.

Then Try the Save PDF By Refresh.

Answer (score 3):

An answer to getting the Copy/CSV/Excel/PDF buttons working is provided [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/50297).

Essentially, a cdn library is referenced instead of the local swf file.  Change your swf path code to:

```
        "tableTools": {
             "sSwfPath": "//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
```

This, along with the standard [initialization](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/initialisation), worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be useful. I implemented extention just for exoprting tables in csv format without using flash: https://github.com/zedxter/DataTablesCSV

Comment: How do you use this extention?  I don't see any documents.  I have included in my view, which is a partial view displayed in a dialog.  I don't see any buttons anywhere.  How do I use it?  I cannot get to GITHUB from work here but managed to copy the contents of the JS file and email to myself with my phone.