# jQuery dataTables - TableTools not working

Tags: csv, flash, datatables, tabletools

I'm using  http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/  in my local-host ( wamp server ). It's working fine, but when I put the same code on my online server, it isn't working.

I am using all latest version of datatables

```js
tableTools: {
    "sSwfPath": "https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
    "sRowSelect": "os",
    "sRowSelector": 'td:first-child',
    // "aButtons": [ "copy", "csv", "xls","pdf","print","select_all", "select_none" ]
    "aButtons": [
        "copy",
        "print", {
            "sExtends": "collection",
            "sButtonText": "Save", // button name 
            // "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
            "aButtons": [
                "csv",
                "xls", {
                    "sExtends": "pdf",
                    "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                    "sPdfMessage": "List of product."
                },
                "print"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Firstly there was no click on copy, pdf, csv, xls  button. Hence I taught my path or swf is not working hence I replaced the link with online link. Hence now I get click, but when I click Copy button it gives me a message ... but when I past in my notepad it's giving me "blank ". Also my pdf, csv, xlsx is not working. Only Print is working perfect. Please let me know what is the issue as in my localhost all is working fine. Its creating issues in my online server.

Comment: when `pdf`, `csv` and `xlsx` is not working, it strongly indicates that the `.swf` is not loaded. Print is a "native" function in TableTools; `pdf`, `csv` and `xlsx` is based on the `.swf`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am pretty sure that datatables.net actively is blocking for use of the `.swf`. Allan Jardine has commented the direct use of the `.swf` files [several times](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/15318/how-to-use-the-cdn-datatables-with-the-cdn-table-tools-setting-sswfpath) :

> datatables.net is not a CDN server and should not be used as such. It
>   is not designed to be, and I might add throttling for hotlinking in
>   future as a huge amount of bandwidth is being used and causing
>   unnecessary load. You'll get much better performance from using a
>   proper CDN or even a locally hosted file.

However, with the introduction of 1.10.x there is finally established a real CDN server, including all the TableTools resources -> http://**cdn**.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/

So replace the `sSwfPath` with :

**http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf**

Comment: @ davidkonrad : thanks for reply and help .. after replacing the link with above link .. now its working ... but when i download Pdf file ..only my first row is seen out of 4 records ..also at side there is word seen select ...where as other thats csv , execl are working properly ..means download records are seen proper ...

Comment: also firstly all was working fine in my localhost : but after replacing with above link ..same .. pdf file is downloaded but records is not seen properly ..also there is word "SELECT" at side

Comment: @user3209031, this must be a problem with the code. Hard to say without seeing the code, or the webpage? Perhaps post a new question with _all_ the relevant code? Sounds very mysterious with a SELECT at the the side :)

Answer (score 4):

I meant you should post it as a completely new question, since it in fact is a new question! :) Anyway. The problem is, that you'll need to render the data, when you produce a PDF. Otherwise you will just get some $(element).text() output, including the select and its options. Like this :

```js
 "aButtons": [ 
      "copy", 
      "csv", 
      "xls",
      { "sExtends":  "pdf",
        "fnCellRender": function ( sValue, iColumn, nTr, iDataIndex ) {
           //extract the value of the select  
           if ( iColumn === 7 ) {
              var val=$(sValue).find('select').val(); 
              return (val!=='') ? val : 'not set';
           }
           //create a dummy text for the HTML-link
           if ( iColumn === 8 ) {
              return 'click';
           }
           return sValue;
         }
      },
      "print",
      "select_all", 
      "select_none" 
  ]
```

see your code here (as close I can get) -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3F8ZJ/**. 
However, you still have a problem caused by your `mRender` rendering, so the column positions is messing up. It breaks the internal `<table>`-structure. Why are you inserting extra `<td>`..`</td>`? But have not time to look into this at the moment.

Comment: thanks you so much.. yes it working but ..some of coloumn is miss match .. will check out it ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

As i want to show proper code format hence post as new answer

@ DAVIDKONRAD : i got to know when i remove ***columnDefs*** from below code then my PDF shows proper records ... btw my csv , excel , print diplay proper record with columnDefs .. only pdf is not showing proper record with "columnDefs"

and i got to know the word which is seen " select " is because of that only ..as i have use dropdown in columndefs

```
 dt = $('#example').DataTable( {
            "dom": '<"clear">T<"clear"><"clear">lfrtip',
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "scrollY": "440px",
            "scrollX": "100%",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "bProcessing": true, 
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "includes/db/server_processing.php",
             "deferRender": true,
            "aaSorting":[[0, "desc"]],
            "aoColumns": [ 
                            { className: "center", },
                            { className: "center", },
                            { className: "center", },
                            { className: "center", },
                            { className: "center", },
                            { className: "center", },
                            { className: "center", },
                               ],
            "columnDefs": [

                            {
                                "aTargets":[7],
                                "fnCreatedCell": function(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol)
                                {
                                $(nTd).css('text-align', 'center');
                                },
                                "mData": null,
                                "mRender": function( data, type, full) {    
                                           return '<td><select id="dynamic_select_'+full[0]+'" name="dynamic_select_'+full[0]+'">\n\
                                                 <option id="0" value="">Select</option/>\n\
                                                 <option id="1_'+full[0]+'" value="test.php?id='+full[0]+'">10</option/>\n\
                                                 <option id="2_'+full[0]+'" value="test2.php?id='+full[0]+'">12</option/>\n\
                                                 <option id="3_'+full[0]+'" value="test3.php?id='+full[0]+'">13</option/>\n\
                                                  </select></td>'; 
                                            //return '<button>Click!</button>';

                                 }

                                },
                              {   
                                "aTargets":[8],
                                "fnCreatedCell": function(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol)
                                {
                                $(nTd).css('text-align', 'center');
                                },
                                "mData": null, 
                                "mRender": function(data, type, full){
                                 //return '<button>Click!</button>';
                                 return '<div id="container"><a href="javascript: void(0);" class="click_'+full[0]+'">Click</a></div>';
                                }
                              }
                           ]
        } );
```