# Datatables export function not working

Tags: jquery, html, google-apps-script, datatables

As per below instructions, Datatables export function worked perfectly in localhost, but not in Google Apps script.

[DataTables TableTools buttons not working correctly (simple example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222554/datatables-tabletools-buttons-not-working-correctly-simple-example)

1. I host the swf file in google drive --> but not SWF file not opening in gdrive.
2. Using drive link ,Set the swf path

   Eg: 
   "sSwfPath":"https://googledrive.com/host/0B_qZnIMaDGX_UFZza0JrNHpRNlE/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
3. Added that drive link in flash setting
4. I updated my script in below link
   http://live.datatables.net/royodij/10/edit

5.When I clicked the drive link, it does not show anything. I need this file to open. as my google apps script uses this file in my Google Site for DATATABLES to export the datatables into pdf, xls.

Can someone help me in giving me a solution:

1. To export the pdf, csv, excel from Datatable in google apps script
2. Open the swf file in google drive

Comment: HEY checkout this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837595/jquery-datatables-tabletools-not-working

Comment: I checked out the above link Getting same Issue. I tried out http://jsfiddle.net/3F8ZJ/ which used HTML 5, ll it work in HTML 4 ? I need to run in GAS script,PLZ SUGGEST ME ANY OTHER SOLUTION ?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from file size, it's not the latest. Anyway, it seems to show now, but TableTools export may not be the best choice for anything except CSV and Print. Everything else is and will stay literally broken. As you may have noticed, it doesn't support UTF8 for PDF, and XLS is actually CSV (again).